# Conversion of Arabic into English and saving into db

Tags: sql, html, arabic

When typing it displays in the Arabic font, but when saving into table it should be saved into the English font.

Can you help me?

Comment: What is the intention? Can you elaborate?

Comment: our project has been developed in english want to convert into arabic so

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want transliteration.

It depends on your platform, but using `iconv()` should work.

Assuming UTF-8...

```
$transliterated = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $str);
```